# xamarin forms 4.6 break ListView?

Tags: listview, xamarin

so I have xamarin.forms `4.5.0.725` in my project, I have a content page, with a listview like this

```
<RefreshView Refreshing="Refresh_Refreshing" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView x:Name="alertsList" SelectionMode="None" SeparatorColor="DimGray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="24" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="someicon"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Message, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Fix" BindingContext="{Binding}" Clicked="Fix_Clicked" FontSize="Small" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</RefreshView>
```

and the button clicked handle

```
void Fix_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayAlert("alert", "button clicked", "ok");
}
```

everything works fine until I update xamarin.form to 4.6 or above,
I tried `4.6.0.1180` `4.7.0.1351` `4.8.0.1364` the button in listview row does not fire click event anymore, I also tried `Command` and `CommandParameter` instead of `Clicked`

anyway to fix this or workaround ?

EDIT: created a sample project [from google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x2kVfwBdTcOcnw1FLuLS-xjM43Iytcn9/view?usp=sharing)

run it, click was fine;
"manage nuget packages for solution", update XF to 4.6.0.1180 or above, run it again, click does not work.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue in the  above XF version  you mentioned.Did you try to delete the obj and bin files ,restart the project.If it still cold not work,try to create a new project.

Comment: yes I did, I also delete the app from android simulator and reinstall @LeoZhu-MSFT , 4.5.0.725 works fine,  4.6.0.1180 or above does not fire click event

Comment: If possible,you could share a sample project,i will test it.

Comment: thank you for your time, please check the project @LeoZhu-MSFT

Comment: Could it work now ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT  no, I could not figure it out what the problem is

Comment: You may give a report to [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues).

Comment: ok, thank you @LeoZhu-MSFT , I asked someone else to try it, got a same result as mine

Comment: You could report this issue to the github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how or why, but it just works if I remove the outer **RefreshView**.
it works on Xamarin.Fomrs `4.5.0.725`,  `4.6.0.1180`, `4.7.0.1351` and `4.8.0.1560`

and tried something more:

keep the **RefreshView**, but remove **Padding="5,0,5,5"**(sample project has) from it,  it also work.

unbelievable...

Answer (score 0):

It's weird,i test it and it works well.

update the XF versin to `4.6.0.1180`

[image]

the effect i run it:

[image]

i'm using

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

Version 16.5.4

Xamarin.Fomrs 4.6.0.1180

Comment: very weird,  I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017  Version 15.9.26,  android 9.0 - API 28

Comment: this is sooo weird, I tried to run on VS Enterprise 2019 v16.7.3, android 9.0 - API 28 (Nexus 10 preset emulator),  same result as VS 2017,  are you sure you rebuild it when you switch to XF 4.6.0.1180 ?

Comment: @Leowan Yes,i rebuild it when i switch to 4.6.0.1180 and it works well.